# Supporting letter for business visa application

Tags: word-choice, business-writing

As part as my application for a business visa, I'm required to provide a supporting letter from my company. However, I'm a bit lost at how to word this correctly, since this is my own company, and I want to come across as professional as possible.

I'm also not sure what kind of level of detail I need to provide, do I need to give specific reasons as to why I'm applying, or would it just be high level "I need to travel to said country to attend to business manners"?

Comment: This might also be a good question for https://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This would depend upon the country you're visiting.  As suggested, it is one for Travel.SE.

Comment: Thanks @towr, I'll also ask the question there. Thought it would be better suited for writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information about you, your company and your business do matter, but not as much as two other factors will..

First, the benefit gained to the respective country and it's entities.
Second, the things which could be or are obstructing the institution to issue your visa.

After setting the layout and syntax for the main info and addressing format, start off by a quick explanation of you, your company and intention in not more than 25 words. After that, quickly jump to the benefits and obstacles and what will you do about them. Assuming you already know them, make sure the words aren't repeated and the text is rich with meaning.

There will be documentation and legal steps that you would either clarify or attach and explain, so that goes as the third and last section of the letter.

Print the letter in PDF and check if browsers open it, revise, add or remove and then send.

Comment: Also, text-alignment of the main body of text should be "Justify" and not Right or Left. Nevertheless, the header and footer of the letter can be justified to a direction, based on your language direction.